# Flaky(Missing Permission) when calling get adaccount, upload custom audience for facebook-java-business-sdk: v16.0.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-java-api

Detailed Description
facebook-java-business-sdk: v16.0.0.0

Currently, I am getting flaky issues when trying to 3 function (I receives success response and failure response whether everything in request stay the same)
1/ Get Ad Accounts
2/ Get Custom Audiences
3/ Upload Custom Audiences

List of errors getting
1/ (#100) Missing Permission
2/ (#100) Unsupported get request
3/ (#100) Unsupported post request
4/ (#100) Unsupported get request
5/ (#10) You do not have sufficient permissions

Extra Information:

**1/ When I switch Meta Apps to a test clone of this App. I don't get Flaky situations and more**

**2/ Our App is on Development environment**

**3/ I am Admin role for this App**

Full Error message

{"error":{"message":"Unsupported post request. Object with ID '238543294XXXXXXX' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100,"error_subcode":33,"fbtrace_id":"AKE5hB_vNjkVJbLFLIBZiCO"}}](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api%22,%22type%22:%22GraphMethodException%22,%22code%22:100,%22error_subcode%22:33,%22fbtrace_id%22:%22AKE5hB_vNjkVJbLFLIBZiCO%22%7D%7D)

{"error":{"message":"(#100) Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"AQQ4X4c9F0n09Aij7LQgs-q"}}](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api%22,%22type%22:%22OAuthException%22,%22code%22:100,%22fbtrace_id%22:%22AQQ4X4c9F0n09Aij7LQgs-q%22%7D%7D)

{"error":{"message":"(#100) Missing permissions","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"A4nZ4aEqEyrRUvEUT56lcuf"}}

{"error":{"message":"(#10) You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this action","type":"OAuthException","code":10,"fbtrace_id":"Aq8oaPXJPPamyHy1faYjY1r"}}

---

Is there a way that I can work around this issues. I can't seem to report this bug to Facebook(Quota limited --> But I haven't report any bug)

Last working noted time was Feb 3, 2023